# How to login from one container to another

Tags: docker, containers

I have 2 containers: `c1` and `c2`. How can I run a script in `c1` from `c2`? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The usual way for one container to cause another container to do something is with a network request, typically HTTP. Check this thread: https://forums.docker.com/t/execute-command-from-a-container-to-another-container.

Comment: You can't directly run commands in one container from another without a lot of workarounds.  The posts I link to describe some of those, with differing degrees of complexity and security risks.